# Code generation with EMF

Tags: eclipse-emf

I want to generate code through EMF in Web page Editor in Eclipse. I am able to add my category in palette. But I have no knowledge about schema & exsd. Where can I get proper knowledge regarding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [EMF: Eclipse Modeling Framework (2nd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=978-0321331885&x=0&y=0) by Dave Steinberg, Frank Budinsky, Marcelo Paternostro and Ed Merks (Dec 26, 2008).

It is the bible when it comes to EMF...

Comment: Thanks,Actually i want to generate code of components while i drag them from palette.For example i have dragged button from palette then corresponding code <input type="button"> should get generated in Editor.What is the way to do it?Is it possible with EMF.

Comment: Yes, it is... Though, I would probably create an internal model and maintain this in the editor and then let the generation of the external file be a separate step. And I would use Xpand for the generation, btw...

Comment: I have created component with GEF.But i am not able to connect it through EMF for code generation.Can you plz explain me in detail that how to connect this model to EMF Code generation.

Comment: It depends a lot on your concrete syntax (the external representation) compared to the abstract syntax (the internal data model). Assume your abstract syntax is optimal as a representation for your GEF `EditParts` and your GEF code is based on this, then the interesting question is whether you can "just" externalize this abstract model using a `XMLResource` to get you external representation. There is a complete chapter on this in the EMF book. If this is not possible, then you can have an JET or - probably better - an Xpand/Xtend transformation to do the the work.

Comment: Thanks for reference.I am trying code generation with Xpand and following link http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-code but i am not able to generate HTML file.Can you please help me out.

Comment: I'll need a hole lot more context before I can help you out.

Comment: I have generated HTML code through Xpand.Apart from this i have created one GMF diagram where i am able to drag & drop but inside it i am not finding any way to link GMF & Xpand.Can you plz help me out.

Comment: GMF... Is the one Eclipse technology I _never_ touch! I just consider it too complicated for any job I have had so far... GEF is fine for most and Graphiti can cover the rest... So sorry, I cannot help you this time.

Comment: Thanks,But can you plz guide me that how after dragging the component from GEF you are generating code.How you are integrating Xpand with GEF?